# Why is my script to start UWSGI not functioning at bootup?

Tags: linux, debian, uwsgi, systemd, init.d

I wonder if you can help.

I am running the following versions:

```
OS: SMP Debian 3.2.81-1 x86_64
uWSGI: uWSGI 2.0.11.2
```

I installed uWSGI manually, as I want to use a specific version. Using the following commands: -

```
apt-get install build-essential psmisc python-dev libxml2 libxml2-dev python-setuptools
cd /opt/
wget http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-2.0.11.2.tar.gz
tar -zxvf uwsgi-2.0.11.2.tar.gz
mv uwsgi-2.0.11.2/ uwsgi/
cd uwsgi/
python setup.py install
```

I am trying to replicate the setup on another server that the project is already working on in a live environment (I am essentially setting up a test server environment).

The original server has uWSGI running on boot. To figure out how this is happening, I used

```
htops
```

I've been able to identify that uWSGI is running on the existing server with a set of command line switches. I've managed to track down the script that initialises uWSGI with these switches in the init.d folder.

I copied this script to my test server, and ran it using

```
service script.sh start
```

After various troubleshooting, mainly involving permissions on socket folders etc, now when I run this script it starts, and if I run htop I can see uWSGI is running and it has the exact same command switches I need.

I thought simply putting the script in init.d and giving it execute permission

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

Would be enough so that it starts when the server is switched on... but this appears to not be the case. Because when I issue

```
reboot
```

At the terminal, the terminal reboots but when I go into htops, and check for the uWSGI process it is not running.

If however directly after reboot I issue the following command

```
service script.sh start
```

The service starts just fine, and I can once again see it in htops.

Research online lead me to the suggestion that I should try to set the script to run automatically using chkconfig. I installed chkconfig using

```
apt-get chkconfig
```

and then ran the following command

```
chkconfig --list
```

I noticed that all the runtime levels where set to off for the script I am trying to get to execute on boot.

I ran the following command

```
chkconfig /etc/init.d/script.sh on
```

And now when I check the script runtime switches with chkconfig, it shows me the following output for my script:

```
script.sh               0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
```

However when I reboot the uWSGI process is still not starting.

Yet if I simply type

```
service script.sh start
```

At the terminal the service runs ok, and uWSGI runs fine.

How can I set the script to run when the server restarts?

---

Edit:

Further research on the live server that is working fine, has determined that it does not appear to be using systemd to launch uWSGI on startup. I logged into the live server and while there is a

```
/etc/systemd
```

folder, it has just one folder in it `system` and no files. The system folder has the following files in it:

```
multi-user.target.wants  sockets.target.wants  syslog.service
```

So there does not appear to be anything uWSGI related in here.

Also what is making me think this is likely something to do with the

```
/etc/init.d
```

folder, is that when I run htop and examine the running services (or daemons) not quite sure of the correct terminology in linux. uWSGI is showing in here as running with a signature of command line switches, and the script I have found in `/etc/init.d` has this exact uWSGI command and same signature of switches, so I'm fairly convinced this is the part of the system that is starting the uWSGI daemon , I just can't figure out what I need to do , to get it to run apart from copying the same file to `/etc/init.d` on the new server and giving it execute permission.

The OS of the live server is :

```
SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u1 x86_64
```

and the OS I am running on the new server is

```
SMP Debian 3.2.81-1 x86_64
```

So they seem fairly similiar? Although I'm not sure how significant the 8 incremements in the least significant digits in the version number is.

On the new server there is no `/etc/systemd` folder , and on the live server there is a `/etc/systemd` as explained above. So it does appear to have been installed seperately to the main OS install (as I have a later version of Debian and it wasn't installed on my system by default) - so perhaps there is something related to systemd that is causing the script to start on the live server, but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 1):

#### Jessie

In the recent Debian (Jessie) the `initv` scripts do not work the way they did.  And given your kernel version you are not running a Debian that uses `initv` scripts.  The current Debian uses `systemd` and scripts in `/etc/rc.d` are run by compatibility features of `systemd` (the `service` command is now a `systemd` command that tries to behave like the old `initv` command).

You have two options:

- Add a line calling the script from `/etc/rc.local`:

  ```
  /etc/rc.d/script.sh
  ```

  This is a rather dirty fix, since it depends on another compatibility feature of `systemd`.  Also, the location of the script does not matter anymore.
- Write a full `systemd` service for `uwsgi` (this is what I do, and what is recommended by the [`uwsgi` documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html)).  You would need to create a file called `/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service` with a content similar to:

  ```
  [Unit]
  Description=uwsgi emperor
  After=rsyslog.service

  [Service]
  PIDFile=/run/uwsgi-emperor.pid
  ExecStart=/bin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
  ExecReload=/bin/uwsgi --reload /run/uwsgi-emperor.pid
  ExecStop=/bin/uwsgi --stop /run/uwsgi-emperor.pid
  Restart=always
  KillSignal=SIGQUIT
  Type=notify
  StandardError=syslog
  NotifyAccess=all

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

  I use the emperor mode (which is also the mode recommended by `uwsgi` for use with `systemd`), although it is possible to hack it to run a single process `uwsgi` (see further reading below).

  You will also need to enable the service to be used by the `multi-user.target`, which will run at boot.  You need to perform this as root:

  ```
  systemctl enable uwsgi.service
  ```

  And `uwsgi` will start with the next boot (it will not start straight away, to make it start you need `systemctl start uwsgi.service`).

Further reading:

- [The Arch linux wiki about `systemd` is very thorough](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd)
- [The Debian wiki on `systemd` is good, but outdated in some places (notably, it tells you that you need to install it which is not the case in Jessie)](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd)

---

#### Weezy

You're mixing things up a little there: `chkconfig` is a script of the RedHat family of OSes.  Making it work for Debian was not easy in the past, and I do not believe it is easy to do so now.

Weezy still uses the `initv` rc.d folders alright, for each runlevel one rc.d folder:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/
/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/
/etc/rc.d/rc2.d/
/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/
/etc/rc.d/rc4.d/
/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/
/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/
```

You can check the runlevel you are in with the (appropriately named) `runlevel` command.  Then you need to check whether there is a softlink to the script in the correct `/etc/rc.d/rc*.d` folder.  If there is no softlink to the script you need to add it with something of the lines:

```
ln -s /etc/rc.d/init.d/script.dh /etc/rc.d/rc$(runlevel | cut -d ' ' -f 2).d/script.sh
```

And that is almost all about how `initv` scripts work.  If you are going into runlevel 2 when the machine boots (I believe that's the default on Debian), what `init` performs is simply `service <script> start` for every file in `/etc/rc.d/rc2.d`.

Comment: Hi grochmal, thanks for your thoughtful and detailed reply. I am running Debian Wheezy on the server. I have checked and systemd doesn't appear to be the means that this is being started on the live server, and I'm trying to replicate that setup as closely as possible. I have updated my question at the bottom with an edit, to share a bit more information about this. Thanks for your input so far, much appreciated.

Comment: Regarding chkconfig - i installed this using apt-get chkconfig and didn't add any additional sources to my /etc/apt/sources.list aside from the offical Debian sources, and it installed fine, I assumed this meant it was likely 'approved' by Debian and likely to work fine, is this a wrong assumption do you think? Many thanks.

Comment: @ICMediaT - Oh cool, given weezy you're almost there.  I have updated the answer with weezy info. (but left jessie info, now titled "jessie", in case someone find this by googling)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts again grochmal, i've checked the live server and there is no rc.d folder, and i've checked the test server and there is also no rc.d folder. Both have a rc.local in /etc but this file is empty on both machines. So there must be some other way to start scripts in Debian Wheezy automatically on boot.

Comment: @ICMediaT - The location of the files can be altered in `/etc/inittab`, or in `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf` (again, depending on the configuration)